# Программы с использованием функции без параметров для вычисления объема конуса

Tags: python

```
def konus():
  r=int(input('enter r:'))
  h=int(input())
  v=1/3*3.14*r**2*h
  return v
print(konus())
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Как по-другому можно составить программу с использованием функции
без параметров для вычисления объема конуса?Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного улучшу вот [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1378078/473641), вам надо в начале файла импортировать встроенную библиотеку `math`, и использовать оттуда переменную `pi`:

```py
import math


def konus():
  r = int(input('enter r:'))
  h = int(input())
  v = 1 / 3 * math.pi * r**2 * h
  
  return v


print(konus())
```

Answer (score 1):

чтобы создать дробное число нужно использовать `.`, а не `,`

```
v=1/3*3.14*r**2*h
```

Comment: но для более точных вычислений, нужно импортировать ```math```, и использовать оттуда переменную ```pi```